# Convert file located in relative path into a Django File object

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a file located at below relative path in my source code:

```
docs/Shootsta_Videographer_critical_info.pdf
```

I want to convert this file into a Django File object. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/file/ states that the File constructor accept a Python file object.

So something like this:

```py
from django.core.files import File
django_file = File(open('<base_dir>/docs/Shootsta_Videographer_critical_info.pdf'))
```